# How can I run summary statistics on pricing data bucketed at the transaction level (or un-bucket the data)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a pricing analysis in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 where I'd like to output some summary statistics about the unit prices we've sold a given SKU at over the last year.

My data is broken out into unique-SKU transactions (where a single row represents all of the units of a single SKU purchased in a single transaction). All units purchased in the transaction would be at the same price, but I can't figure out how to calculate summary statistics since multiple units (observations) are rolled up into a single line item.

Are there functions that take observation count into consideration when calculating average, standard deviation, percentile rank, etc.?

Or is there a clean way to blow the transactions out so that a transaction with 10 units becomes 10 rows with one unit per row?

Example:
How the data is (bucketed):

```
Transaction Number; SKU id; Unit Count; Unit Price; Total Price
1   ABC 3   2   6
2   ABC 2   4   8
3   ABC 5   1   5
4   ABC 1   5   5
```

How the data probably needs to be (Blown Out):

```
Transaction Number; SKU id; Unit Count; Unit Price; Total Price
1   ABC 1   2   2
1   ABC 1   2   2
1   ABC 1   2   2
2   ABC 1   4   4
2   ABC 1   4   4
3   ABC 1   1   1
3   ABC 1   1   1
3   ABC 1   1   1
3   ABC 1   1   1
3   ABC 1   1   1
4   ABC 1   5   5
```

Difference in Statistical Calculations:

```
Statistic;  Bucketed;   Blown Out
Average Unit Price: 3.0 2.2
Median Unit Price:  3.0 2.0
StDev Unit Price:   1.8 1.5
```

Are there statistical functions that take in something like "observation count" or is there an easy way to blow my data out so that each row represents a unit (instead of a transaction which may aggregate multiple units)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select transaction, sku, count, unitprice, totalprice, 1 as n
      from t
      union all
      select transaction, sku, count, unitprice, totalprice, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < count
    ) 
select *
from cte;
```

If the counts exceed 100, then add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

You can also use a numbers table, if you have one handy.  Recursive CTEs are more interesting and the performance is usually acceptable.

Comment: This was the correct answer and I appreciated the template code!